# Simple Html Dom not getting page data

Tags: html, dom

I have this code

```
//st
$html = file_get_html('https://detail.1688.com/offer/608805456868.html');

$list = $html->find('h1[class="d-title"]');
foreach ( $list as $item ) {
 echo $item->outertext . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I wanted to get the title of this product but is not working, please can someone help me

Comment: If it's the same site, you are showing here... that could an authentication  issue. Think about curl to pass login credentials...

Comment: The page is not protected